# mod_wsgi for windows with apache 2 and Python 2.6

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi, python-2.6

I am using apache 2.0.64 and python 2.6.

There is mod_wsgi version avialable for apache 2.2. I have integrated it successfully. But I want to configure it with  apache 2.0. Because of some other dependency I had to down grade my apache version into 2.0.

When I am trying to ingrate "mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py26-3.3.so" with apache 2.0, it gives module load error. There are number of downloads available at mod_wsgi download page.

[http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+Size+DownloadCount](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/downloads/list?can=1&q=&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20Size%20DownloadCount)

Is anyone know the mod_wsgi version compatible with  apache 2.0 and python 2.6?

Answer (score 1):

The "ap22" portion of the filename suggests that the module is built for Apache 2.2, methinks, and thus will only work with a v2.2 build.

I don't see on that page any built for Apache 2.0... Can you compile your own?

Comment: I tried with that module too. But I am getting following error and apache doesn't starts when that module is enabled. "Cannot load C:/Program Files/Apache Group/Apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The specified module could not be found."

Comment: Tried with which other module? The one you compiled yourself? How did you go about compiling it if you did? The makefiles supplied with mod_wsgi source code are setup for Apache 2.2 and you would need to have modified them to build against Apache 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, but the fact is, mod-wsgi ver 3.3 does not work with Apache 2.4. Also, the binaries given on that page specify that the binaries are for 32-bit systems. So, if you're running a 64-bit system, you will need 64-bit binary .so file.
So, you're better going around compiling the source code.